# Proc Report issue : I am getting a value selected into variable

Tags: sas

I have a macro like:

```
%macro links;
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE T_US  AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
    ID_SECON,
    NO_BEN,
    s_an
     FROM rm.BENEF
;
QUIT; 

proc sql;
    select max(input(substr(s_an,1,4),4.)) into :max_sign
    from T_US
;
quit;
%mend links;
```

Then I create a report using ODS:

```
%macro theRep();

options topmargin=1in bottommargin=1in
        leftmargin=0.25in rightmargin=0.25in
;

ods tagsets.ExcelXP path="&cheminEx." file="&fi" style=seaside
options(autofit_height="yes"
        pagebreaks="yes"
        orientation="portrait"
        papersize="letter"
        WIDTH_POINTS = "12" WIDTH_FUDGE = ".0625"
        absolute_column_width="110,175,180,200"
        );

ods escapechar="^";

%theODS;

ods tagsets.ExcelXP close;
ods listing;
%mend theRep;

%macro theODS;
ods tagsets.ExcelXP 
options(sheet_interval="none"
        sheet_name="thename"
        );

proc report data=T_US nowindows spanrows missing noheader
    style(report)=[frame=box rules=all
        foreground=black Font_face='Times New Roman' font_size=10pt
        background=none]
    style(column)=[Font_face='Times New Roman' font_size=10pt just=left]
;

    col ID_SECON NO_BEN s_an;

    define ID_SECON / group order=data noprint;
    define NO_BEN / style(column)=[verticalalign=top];
    define s_an / style(column)=[verticalalign=top];

    compute before ID_SECON / style=[verticalalign=middle background=#f0f0f                     foreground=blue fontweight=bold font_size=12pt];
    line ID_SECON $25.;
    endcomp ;

    title j=center height=12pt 'The title';
run;

%mend theODS;
```

The report is showing nice. But the problem is:

The value of the variable max_sign is displayed at the end of the report even if I did not asked for it in the define part.

Please, can you help? Why the variable which is not in the dataset T_US appears in the report?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some sample values for `s_an` variable, or the expected value construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the value of max_sign is being displayed because of this step:

```
proc sql;
    select max(input(substr(s_an,1,4),4.)) into :max_sign
    from T_US
;
quit;
```

Not the `PROC REPORT`. Try adding the `NOPRINT` option to suppress output from `PROC SQL`:

```
proc sql NOPRINT;
    select max(input(substr(s_an,1,4),4.)) into :max_sign
    from T_US
;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was what I missed.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL `:into` clause transfers a value from a select query into one or more macro variables depending on syntax.  The select output is not automatically suppressed when you use `:INTO`.  SQL output is suppressed using the `NOPRINT` option, or `RESET NOPRINT;` statement (SQL-only).

So you will want

```
proc sql noprint;
  select max(input(substr(s_an,1,4),4.)) into :max_sign
  from T_US
;
```

The `:INTO` clause also has a `TRIMMED` option that is helpful when *transferred* values are used in a title or footnote and the 'default' transfer has leading or trailing spaces.

```
into :max_sign TRIMMED
```

Comment: Thank you for these explanations, and for answering me even if I did not give examples. It was evening, I was out of work.

Answer (score 0):

As the others pointed out, the trick is in using `into :(some name)` and `noprint`. Additionally you shall be aware that a macrovariable is a character string by nature. Why does it matter? If you store a number in a macrovariable, it is stored digit by digit exactly as you input it; it is highly advisable, thus, to format the number prior to assigning it to the macrovariable.

In other words, if the true value is `2.36581` and you format it as `2.4` and assign it to a macrovariable there is no way to get the higher precision back. All that is stored in the macrovariable is "two, fullstop, four".